# Unweighted Graph Method 'count' Runtime Error

Tags: java, graph, nodes

My assignment is to create a non-directed, unweighted graph class called Graph. My second part is to create a method 'count' which is passed a Graph object as an argument and returns a
count of the number of connected components in the graph.

For some reason whenever I run this 'count' method, I get returned 'I expect '1'. I think my error has to do with my 'getToVertices' method, which says all of these nodes are connected, even though I don't believe I made them connected purposefully. Attached is my getToVertices method and my 'count' method.

It's suppose to return 3, the connected nodes and 2 unconnected nodes. Am I missing something?

```
public QueueInterface<T> getToVertices(T vertex)
  // Returns a queue of the vertices that vertex is adjacent to.
  {
    QueueInterface<T> adjVertices = new LinkedQueue<T>();
    int fromIndex;
    int toIndex;
    fromIndex = indexIs(vertex);
    for (toIndex = 0; toIndex < numVertices; toIndex++)
      if (edges[fromIndex][toIndex] != true)
        adjVertices.enqueue(vertices[toIndex]);
    return adjVertices;
  }

public class CountCC {
    private static int count(Graph <String> graph)
    {
        int count = 0; 

          StackInterface<String> stack = new LinkedStack<String>();
          QueueInterface<String> vertexQueue = new LinkedQueue<String>();

          String currVertex;      // vertex being processed
          String adjVertex;   
          String startVertex;

          graph.clearMarks();


        while(graph.getUnmarked() != null)
        {
            startVertex = graph.getUnmarked();
            graph.markVertex(startVertex);
            stack.push(startVertex);

              do
              {
                currVertex = stack.top();
                stack.pop();
                System.out.println(currVertex);
                vertexQueue = graph.getToVertices(currVertex);


                while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty())
                  {
                    adjVertex = vertexQueue.dequeue();

                    if (!graph.isMarked(adjVertex))
                    {
                      graph.markVertex(adjVertex);
                      stack.push(adjVertex);
                    }
                  }

              } while (!stack.isEmpty());
              count++;
              System.out.println(graph.getUnmarked());  


        }
        return count; 
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {

Graph<String> graph1=new Graph<String>();

String s0 = new String("0   ");
String s1 = new String("1    ");
String s2 = new String("2    ");
String s3 = new String("3    ");
String s4 = new String("4    ");

graph1.clearMarks();

graph1.addVertex(s0);
graph1.addVertex(s1);
graph1.addVertex(s2);
graph1.addVertex(s3);
graph1.addVertex(s4);

graph1.addEdge(s0, s1);
graph1.addEdge(s1, s2);
graph1.addEdge(s2, s0);

System.out.println("I expect "+ count(graph1)); 

}
}
```

Comment: It will be difficult to help without seeing the `Graph` class.

Comment: You're absolutely right @JimGarrison. I ended up fixing a method in my Graph class. I will delete this question soon.